# Why exactly did Lock request Morpheus's immediate counsel here?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Reloaded* (2003), Captain Morpheus meets Mifune:

> A.P.U. Escort : Commander Lock demands!...
>
> Mifune : [interruptingly clears his throat].
>
> A.P.U. Escort : ...**Requests your immediate counsel**, sir!

Why exactly did Lock request Morpheus's immediate counsel?

Comment: Presumably because he wanted to yell at him for disobeying a direct order. But there are forms that need to be followed, and one of those is that *captains aren't summoned, they're requested.*

Answer (score 1):

If you take the inciting incident, Morpheus asking one captain to say behind, and then the confrontation with Lock. Knowing that Lock and Morpheus don't get along because of the shared love interest of Niobe. And Lock is a pragmatist in contrast to Morpheus' faith in the One. It all boils down to Lock wants to punish Morpheus for insubordination. Mifune clearing his throat to have the APU guard soften his tone is exactly what he says it is. He is there trying to keep the peace between Morpheus (and his faction of followers) and the main army.

From the [script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/the-matrix-reloaded-2003.pdf):

> **NIOBE** We do what Commander Lock ordered
> us to do. Evacuate from broadcast
> levels and return to Zion.
> ...
> **MORPHEUS**
> I'm asking for one ship to remain
> in our place in case the Oracle
> should attempt to contact us.
> **BALLARD**
> Bullshit., you're asking for one of
> us to deliberately disobey a
> direct order.
> **MORPHEUS**
> That's right, I am. But as we well
> know, the reason that most of us
> are here is our afinity for
> disobedience.
> **ROLAND**
> What happens if you get back to
> Zion and the Commander throws you
> in the stockade?
> **MORPHEUS**
> He won't.
> Ballard bursts into laughter.
> **BALLARD**
> Goddamnnit, Morpheus, you ain't
> never gonna change. Shit, I'll do
> it, just to see what Deadbolt does
> to you. You got thirty-six hours,
> but that's all.

Later in Lock's office

> **MORPHEUS**
> Commander Lock.
> **LOCK**
> I have spoken to the other
> Captains and I wanted to offer you
> the chance to explain your
> actions.
> **MORPHEUS**
> I was not aware my actions required any explanation.
> **LOCK**
> You were given a direct order to return to Zion.
> **MORPHEUS**
> I did.
> **LOCK**
> But you asked for one ship to remain behind.
> **MORPHEUS**
> I would have stayed but we needed to re-charge.
> **LOCK**
> You admit to a direct contravention of your duty--
> **MORPHEUS**
> We need a presence in the Matrix to await contact from the Oracle--
> **LOCK**
> I don't want to hear that shit! I don't care about Oracles or prophecies or Messiahs! I care about one thing, stopping that army from destroying this city and to do that I need soldiers to obey my orders.